# Parse an ResponseStatus into Response

Tags: java, response, saml

I need to return something into `Response` class format but I have an `SAMLResult` variable so when I get the Status (`ResponseStatus`) I don't find any way to parse it to a `Response`variable.

Has someone any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, you are only interested in the numeric SAMLResponse status and need to return this as a new value of type `Response`.

So you can simply build a new Response with the SAMLResponse status value:

```
int samlStatus = SAMLResponse.ResponseStatus;
Response response = Response.status(samlStatus).build();
return response;
```

Or you can intantiate a new `Response` object (by implementing all methods from the abstract Response class e.g. with default values) and set the `SAMLResponse.ResponseStatus` value in the `getStatus()` method. For example:

```
Response response = new Response() {
    @Override
    public int getStatus() {
        int samlStatus = SAMLResult.ResponseStatus;
        return samlStatus;
    }
    // override all other Response methods ...
}
return response;
```